# ReferenceError: options is not defined

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

ReferenceError: options is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\khair\Documents\GitHub\WideDiscord\index.js:171:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Here is the code

```
    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "cat",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"
        }
};
}


request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }


    $ = cheerio.load(responseBody); 


    var links = $(".image a.link");

    var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
    
    console.log(urls);

    if (!urls.length) {
       
        return;
    }

    // Send result
    message.channel.send( urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a "}" beneath the options Object definition, which tells me options is being defined within a function, so even though it's a var, it's undefined outside of whatever function it's in.

To fix this, call requests() within the same scope as options's definition, so requests() will see the data within options.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to follow along with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFtTTCbGwYY&ab_channel=CodeLyon
Look carefully, he defined `options` and `request` under the same function called `image`